# Is "you will give me the photos that you would make" the correct tense for this sentence?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

> We will meet in fourteen days and you will give me the photos that **you would make** meanwhile.

I am not sure what tense is appropriate in the last part of the sentence. It is referred to the future when photos will be already made so I would use the future in the past. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is a good case for the future perfect:

> We will meet in fourteen days and (at that time) you will give me the photos that you **will have taken** (in the meantime).

The verb tells us that you *have yet to take* the photos, but I expect you *will have done so* by the time we next meet.  So, "in the meantime" is somewhat redundant, but you can include it for clarity.

Note that it's not idiomatic to *make* photographs.  Instead we *take* them.

Comment: Can 'make photographs' be understood Photoshop them, instead take them in this context?

Comment: @dan That sounds fine to me at least, since you’ve clarified the context. I don’t frequent this site, but I am a native speaker.

Comment: @dan  "Photoshop" (or just "shop") is itself a verb, "to *photoshop* a photograph" means to alter it digitally.  You can *make* a picture in Photoshop, but a photograph is *taken* with some kind of camera.